# Can we use ros kinatic on nvidia jetson platfrom?

Tags: ros

I am using Ros kinetic. Now I am trying to use this in jetson nano, but jetson jetpack allows ubuntu 18.04, but kinetic allows 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

The officially supported release for Jetson Nano is Ubuntu 18.04 right now. I'm also unaware of any 16.04 image that exists for the Nano. As you stated, you cannot use Kinetic with 18.04, however you can use Melodic; this would be my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Jetson Nano supports Ubuntu 18 only. For Ubuntu 18 you can only install ROS Melodic. I am attaching some reference links:

https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/install-ubuntu-16-04-system-on-nano/122666

https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/installing-ros-on-nano/71845/9

http://wiki.ros.org/Distributions